# What's the difference between trivial case, base case, and edge case?

Tags: algorithm, terminology

I have run into these terms quite often when talking about algorithms.

**Trivial case**

**Base case**

**Edge case**

Are they all the same? or is there any significant difference between those?

Comment: Maybe more appropriate at [ELL.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)? Trivial case is something that simple that one shouldn't need a description, very easy to solve. Base case is the non-recursing scenario in recursion (length of an empty sequence, factorial of zero...). Edge case is something where bugs are likely to arise because many people will not remember to check for them, typicaly found at edges of domain (e.g. empty strings, division by zero, negative lengths...) They are definitely not same.

Comment: I think this depends on the context. In recursion, what's called the "base case" is e.g. "n is zero" or "list is empty" (the other case ,when the recursive function is called again, does not really have a name here). In other contexts you might call this the "trivial case", whereas a 'normal' input is the "base case". I think the problem is that "base" can be interpreted either as "normal" _or_ as "simple". Where exactly did you hear those terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "trivial case" is a case which a simple, limited algorithm could still solve. For instance, the case where you need to sort a list of numbers, but they're already sorted.

A "base case" is usually used in relation to recursion, and refers to the case which is handled directly, without any further recursion. For instance, quicksorting a single element. (Base cases are usually also trivial.)

An "edge case" is a case which is unusual in some way, which is not properly handled by logic which works for most cases, or which leads to particularly poor performance or results. For instance, quicksorting an array with all elements being equal, making it impossible to choose an efficient pivot.

Comment: What about "non-trivial case"?

Comment: That’s a case which is not a trivial case.

Answer (score 2):

Let's talk about below algorithm of factorial

```
factorial (n) = n * factorial (n - 1) if n > 0
              = 1 if n is 0
              = error if n < 1
```

**Trivial case**: Simple cases which should pass if the algorithm is sane. (Similar to smoke test) Usually one can calculate this in mind or with pen and paper. Example factorial(3) or factorial(5)
**Base case**: Terminating condition in recursion where algorithm converges to. n is 0 in this case.
**Edge case**: Cases where algorithm might give wrong answer because of language limitation (variable overflow, division by zero etc) or cases where algorithm is expected to report an error gracefully instead of breaking down.